# setState in functional component don't keep value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component that keeps a state. This state I try to manipulate using an `onClick` event in an SVG. The SVG is in another component and has the `addAndRemoveSelectedCabin` method passed to it via props. I loop through the elements in an `useEffect` and add an `eventListener`. This doesn't work. The `useEffect` with the `selectedCabins` dependency logs the new number only. It seems the state returns to the initial state after every `stateChange`.

This is the state and method in the parent component.

```
const [selectedCabins, setSelectedCabins] = useState([0]);

const addRemoveSelectedCabin = id => {
  const newArr = [...selectedCabins, id];

  setSelectedCabins(newArr);
}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(selectedCabins);
}, [selectedCabins])
```

This is how I call the method. [UPDATE]

```
useEffect(() =>
{
  const cabins = document.querySelectorAll(".cabin");

  cabins.forEach(cabin =>
  {
    const id = cabin.getAttributeNS(null, "id").substring(1, 5);
    const found = cabinsData.find(el => el.id === id)
    if (found && found.status === "available")
    {
      cabin.classList.add("green")
      cabin.addEventListener('click', () => addRemoveSelectedCabin(id));
    } else if (found && found.status === "booked")
    {
      cabin.classList.add("gray")
    }
  })
}, [])
```

Console:

```
[0]

(2) [0, "1105"]

(2) [0, "1101"]
```

This works if I put the `onClick` directly in the SVG element. Does anyone know why this is?

```
<rect
  id="C1105"
  x="749.4"
  y="58.3"
  className="cabin"
  width="36.4"
  height="19.9"
  onClick={() => addRemoveSelectedCabin(1105)}
>
  <title>1105</title>
</rect>
```

Comment: Where does the variable `id` in your _eventListener_ come from? Or you perhaps try to: `cabin.addEventListener('click', ({ currentTarget }) => addRemoveSelectedCabin(currentTarget.id));`?

Comment: You don't need to add an event listener. Just use the `onClick` prop.

Comment: If you call `cabin.addEventListener('click', () => addRemoveSelectedCabin(id));` only once then `addRemoveSelectedCabin` will always refer to the function that was created the first time the component was rendered and at that time `selectedCabins` was `[0]`. Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: My problem is that I really need to add this event listener programmatically. It's not all the elements that should have a click listener. So hard coding it is not an option.

Comment: What version of React are you running? Ran into a problem similar to this yesterday when using a functional component as context provider.

Comment: @Kryptor, definitely, you are in a wrong way, because you think passing `onClick` to each SVG is a hard code way, but it is a proper react solution. here you code ReactJS, not pure JavaScript. so passing `onClick` is the right way.

Comment: @AmerllicA True. But this should work. Sounds more like a React bug to me

Comment: @JesseSchokker, it should not. because we don't know how Kryptor select the DOM elements, Does he use `useRef``? or not. I believe he should read ReactJS docs deeper.

Comment: Sounds like the ol' closure in a loop issue, but you haven't posted enough code to say. Show us your loop. Also note that your code will never remove cabins from the array.

Comment: @JaredSmith, added the whole loop for you guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you are binding `addRemoveSelectedCabin` *in the first render*. `useEffect` is only executed once since you pass an empty dependency list. `addRemoveSelectedCabin` closes over `selectedCabins` which at that point in time has the value `[0]`.

[Why am I seeing stale props or state inside my function?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function)  from the React documentation has more information about this.

The solution in your case is simple: Pass a function to the setter to get the "current" state value. Don't reference the state value in the component:

```
const addRemoveSelectedCabin = id => {
  setSelectedCabins(selectedCabins => [...selectedCabins, id]);
}
```

---

Having said that, this is still an odd thing to do in React world. You should reevaluate your assumptions that make you think you have to do it that way.

> It's not all the elements that should have a click listener.

Depending on how you actually render the elements, that's easy to do. JSX/React is just JavaScript. Whether you have a condition that adds the event handler or not or whether you have a condition that sets `onClick` or not is basically the same.

But without a more complete example there is not much we can suggest.